# How is it this won't work in either jQuery UI 3.3.1 or 1.9.1, but works in 1.9.2 only?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle

Whilst looking for a solution to toggle a text box from the tick of a check box, I came across this fiddle from another post here in StackOverflow.

http://jsfiddle.net/67x4bwnr/

**html**

```
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Toggle</h3>
    <p>
  Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<select name="effects" id="effectTypes">
  <option value="blind">Blind</option>
  <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
  <option value="drop">Drop</option>
  <option value="explode">Explode</option>
  <option value="fold">Fold</option>
  <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
  <option value="puff">Puff</option>
  <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
  <option value="scale">Scale</option>
  <option value="shake">Shake</option>
  <option value="size">Size</option>
  <option value="slide">Slide</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="run_effect" name="run_effect"> Click to execute effect
```

**javascript+jquery**

```
function runEffect() {
  // get effect type from
  var selectedEffect = 'slide';

  // most effect types need no options passed by default
  var options = {};
  // some effects have required parameters
  if ( selectedEffect === "scale" ) {
    options = { percent: 0 };
  } else if ( selectedEffect === "size" ) {
    options = { to: { width: 200, height: 60 } };
  }

  // run the effect
  $( "#effect" ).toggle( selectedEffect, options, 500 );
};

 $( "#effect" ).toggle( false );
// set effect from select menu value
$("#run_effect").click(function(){
    if($('#run_effect').is(':checked')){
        runEffect();
    }else{
        runEffect();
    }
});
```

**css**

```
.toggler {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #button {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #effect {
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 0.4em;
  }
  #effect h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.4em;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

The fiddle will only work using jQuery 1.9.2. I tried it using 3.3.1, 1.9.1, and it won't work.

So, my first question is: **How is that?**

And second question is: **How to make it work using 3.3.1?**

Please bear in mind that I'm no front-end dev, so all this is like "chinese" for me.

Comment: The fiddle you linked to is using jQuery 1.9.1? I think that maybe you're confused, as it also requires jQuery***UI*** 1.9.2, which is a completely separate library which also needs to be included in your page

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan this is using the jQuery UI `.toggle()` http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/  jQuery UI is dependent upon jQuery but not the same thing.  It is like pulling a trailer with a truck, you still need the truck (jQuery) here, even if you buy a new truck (3.3.n version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery as well as the CSS and script for jQuery UI.  Example (see top of HTML)

Now as to why/how to use the jsFiddle there, that is their design decision to not include the jQuer UI toggle when other versions except 1.9.1 are the chosen jQuery version.

NOTE: that answers your question.

NOW I had a bit of fun with this and wired up your select/checkbox and added a button to show the chosen effect when clicked.  Made an object out of the conditionals and used that, feel free to just use the "answer" here.  It still fires the "change" event - by clicking the button so it does NOT show any effect if it is unchecked, just does the show/hide basic jQuery there.

```js
function runEffect(pick, choice) {
  // get effect type from
  var selectedEffect = choice.val(); //'slide';
  // console.log(selectedEffect);
  let defaultOptions = {
    duration: 500,
    scale: {
      options: {
        percent: 0
      }
    },
    size: {
      options: {
        to: {
          width: 200,
          height: 60
        }
      }
    }
  };
  let options = defaultOptions[selectedEffect] ? (defaultOptions[selectedEffect].options ? defaultOptions[selectedEffect].options : {}) : {};
  // run the effect IF checked?
  if (pick) {
    $("#effect").toggle(selectedEffect, options, defaultOptions.duration);
  } else {
    // just basic jquery hide/show toggle
    $("#effect").toggle();
  }
};
// this is an alias for and the same as $("#effect").hide();
$("#effect").toggle(false);

// set effect from select menu value
// this is better with '.on(' and should use "change" not click
$("#run_effect").on('change', function() {
  let me = $(this).is(':checked');
  let choice = $('#effectTypes');
  runEffect(me, choice);
});
$("#show-effect").on('click', function() {
  $("#run_effect").trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.toggler {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

#button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#effect {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 0.4em;
}

#effect h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Toggle</h3>
    <p>
      Etiam libero neque, luctus a, eleifend nec, semper at, lorem. Sed pede. Nulla lorem metus, adipiscing ut, luctus sed, hendrerit vitae, mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<select name="effects" id="effectTypes">
  <option value="blind">Blind</option>
  <option value="bounce">Bounce</option>
  <option value="clip">Clip</option>
  <option value="drop">Drop</option>
  <option value="explode">Explode</option>
  <option value="fold">Fold</option>
  <option value="highlight">Highlight</option>
  <option value="puff">Puff</option>
  <option value="pulsate">Pulsate</option>
  <option value="scale">Scale</option>
  <option value="shake">Shake</option>
  <option value="size">Size</option>
  <option value="slide" selected>Slide</option>
</select>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="run_effect" name="run_effect"> Click to execute effect javascript+jquery</label>
<button type="button" id="show-effect">Do Effect Show</button>
```

Comment: This makes it! As before-mentioned by @Rory McCrossen, I was confused with jQuery and jQuery UI, and the way jsfiddle.net integrated both jQuery versions differently. Thanks for your time! :D